# How to do a source import with GitHub APIv3

Tags: github, postman, github-api-v3

background:
I am trying to build an application that will copy a public repository to the logged in account.

Now i am trying to do a source import in PostMan and i am using the following settings:

i make a PUT request to this link:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{myusername}/{empty github repository}/import
```

with the following header:

```
Accept:application/vnd.github.barred-rock-preview
```

With this body:

```
{
  "vcs": "git",
  "vcs_url": "https://github.com/{owner of repo i want to copy}/{repo i want to copy}",
  "vcs_username": "{myusername}",
  "vcs_password": "{mypassword}"
}
```

I have read the [github API for importing repositories](https://developer.github.com/v3/migrations/source_imports/#start-an-import). But i am getting the following response from the server:

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": 
  "https://developer.github.com/v3/migrations/source_imports/#start-an-import"
}
```

Why does the server return a Not Found? How do i get this to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It need [Authentication](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication) else will get `404 Not Found`

using username and password for authentication

Put URL:

```
https://{myusername}:{mypassword}@api.github.com/repos/{myusername}/{myreponame}/import
```

Request Body

```
{
  "vcs": "git",
  "vcs_url": "https://github.com/{ownerRepo}/{ownerRepoName}"
}
```

`vcs_username` and `vcs_password` used for remote repo not yours.

Comment: This worked, thanks! When i tried using an oauth2 token i had the wrong scopes for my token.